# pipeline as find's -exec argument

Tags: shell, command-line, find, pipe

Is it possible to use a pipeline command as an argument to find's `-exec` option? This means, I want to do something like this:

```
find . -name CMakeLists* -exec cat '{}' | grep lib \;
```

where I am trying to execute `cat '{}' | grep lib` for each file,
but this doesn't work. Neither does quoting work. Does anyone have any advice?

**Update:**

The particular question was answered. Now, is there a way for a generic `find <path> -type f -name <name> -exec <pipeline-command>` pattern to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "CMakeLists*" -exec grep lib /dev/null {} +
```

This finds *files* in the current directory whose basename begins or is the string `CMakeLists`.  The argument is escaped (double quoted) so that the shell doesn't expand it before `find` runs.

There is no need to add `cat` with a pipe to `grep` --- it's a useless process with useless IO, here.  Adding `/dev/null` insures that `grep` will report the filename along with the matching line(s) when there is more than one file to match.

By using `{} +` as the terminating sequence to the `-exec` argument, multiple filenames are passed to each invocation of the `grep` command.  Had we used `{} \;` then a `grep` process would have been spawned for *every* file found.  Needless process instantiation is expensive if done hundreds or thousands of times.

To use a pipe with a `find` `-exec` argument, you need to invoke the shell.  A contrived example could be to `grep` for the string "one" but only if the string "two" isn't present too.  This could be done as:

```
find . -type f -name "CMakeLists*" -exec sh -c 'grep one "$@"|grep -v two' sh {} +
```

This is predicated on the comments, below, by @muru, @Serg and @Scott, with thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I thinkI think you missed a closing quote.

Comment: @FloHe No, this is the opening quote that is missing => `-name "CMakeLists*"`. Never forget the quote, else you may have an unexpected result if there is a file whose name begins with CMakeLists in your current directory.

Comment: IIRC (not sure, though), multiple uses of `{}` in the `-exec` command may cause problems in some systems. Use `sh -c 'grep one "$0" | grep -v two' {} \;` instead

Comment: Muru is correct, single argument is preferred. Multiple arguments can result in unspecified behavior. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12965441/3701431

Comment: In addition to @muru’s comment, (1) not only should you not use `{}` more than once in your command, but you should not use it as *part* of a command, as in `-exec sh -c 'grep one {} | grep -v two'` (1a) because it might not work, and (1b) because it can give rise to code injection vulnerabilities.    (2) It may be even better to do `-exec sh -c 'grep one "$1" | grep -v two' sh {} \;`.  (2a) It’s better to have `$0`=`sh` in case the shell issues error messages.  (2b) This scales more readily to `-exec sh -c 'grep one "$@" | grep -v two' sh {} +`.

Comment: @Scott - with thanks for pointing out the issues with multiple instances of {} I've incorporated them as an update.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that's not how the find command terminates.

Secondly, you can just replace `cat` with `grep lib`.

`find . -name CMakeLists* -exec grep lib '{}' \;`

Which basically means "execute grep lib" on each of the search results. You can even omit the ticks around {}. Should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks: 'find . -name CMakeLists* -exec grep lib '{}' \;' worked. But the general question remains: Is it possible to use the exec option with a piped command

Comment: Yes, but this is not the case here. -exec is a flag of the find command. It just calls on an external program to be executed on the results of the FIND command one by one(files by file). You can pipe the results of whatever processing you made to your search results into `wc` or `sort` or append the results of your processing to a file with `>>`.
If you want to execute some other command on the search results that have already been processed with some other program called by `-exec` on a "per file" basis, you should look into `xargs`.
Can you please clarify what you're trying to do here?

Comment: The thing is I want to find  all files named CMakeLists in the current folder and all its subdirectories, then printing all the contents of the different files with a leading #/path/tothe/file/CMakelist (before the content) to stdout and finally redirecting the complete output via `>>` into a new file. Is this possible with a `find -exec <pipe-command>` pattern?

Comment: @FloHe This is not possible the way you have done it in your original question. The answers here by Max and JRFerguson are good. If you are not statisfied because they do not deal with the pipe (because there is no need for it to do a grep), then rephrase your question. Not here in the comments, I mean the original question at the top of the page.

Comment: @FloHe If you want the grep results preceded with the full path of the file, see JRFerguson's answer, or use GNU grep's `-H` flag with this answer.

Comment: Okay, this should work:

`find . -name CMakeLists* -exec grep -l lib {} \; | xargs cat >> newfile`

In this case grep will output only the file names that contain the string "lib" (-l flag) and print all the contents of such files to a new file(`newfile`, in this example).
`xargs` will execute `cat >> newfile` on each one of the search results.
I'll clarify to include stdout in a moment.